# Rxjs Update Observable value silently without notifying subscriber

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to update an observable silently so for the next value subscribers are not notified.
I'm using Angular Reactive Forms and subscribing to form control value changes Observable as follows.

```
this.form.get('someSelection').valueChanges.susbscribe(value => this.selectionValue = value);
```

In some cases, I want to manually update the value of the control but by doing so the valueChanges observable emits the new value. Is there any way to silently update the observable without notifying the subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `emitEvent` option when setting a new value :

```
this.form.setValue(value, {emitEvent:false});
```